# Caching visited page in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, caching, cordova

I work on Jquery Mobile/Phonegap app for android.
I´d like my app to "remember" that(if) the user has visited one of my pages. For example if he once visits "page1.html", this action should be cached in the phone memory, so that when the user opens the app again there should be possibility to navigate to this "page2.html" directly from "index.thml".
Please, if you have a code suggestion, tell me also how/where do I use it, because sometimes for starters like me it is realy hard to understand what to do with a little piece code.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 local storage for this purpose.

Each time when a page is shown you can save/update the current page URL to a local storage variable, say 'lastVisit', as below:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function (event, data) { 

    var currentPage =  $('.ui-page-active').data('url');       
    localStorage.setItem("lastVisit", currentPage); 

});
```

If you are not getting $('.ui-page-active').data('url'), then you can use $.mobile.activePage.attr('id') which will give you the current page id.

So next time, when the user opens the app again, you can check whether this local storage variable is set and can action accordingly.

The code will look like as below:

```
$(document).on('mobileinit', function(){

    var lastVisit = '';

    if(localStorage.getItem("lastVisit") != null){
        lastVisit = localStorage.getItem("lastVisit");
    }  
    if(lastVisit){
        document.location.href = lastVisit;
    }

});
```

You can use these codes in the header section scripts.

Comment: Please mark tick if this answer was useful to you. (Also please up-vote). Thanks...